# Remove Tags from processed text in R

Tags: r, nlp

I have the text below

```
txt <- c("This is a short tagging example, by John Doe.",
     "Too bad OpenNLP is so slow on large texts.")
```

Code for extraction

```
extractPOS = function(x, thisPOSregex) {
x <- as.String(x)
wordAnnotation <- annotate(x, list(Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(), Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()))
POSAnnotation <- annotate(x, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), wordAnnotation)
POSwords <- subset(POSAnnotation, type == "word")
tags <- sapply(POSwords$features, '[[', "POS")
thisPOSindex <- grep(thisPOSregex, tags)
tokenizedAndTagged <- sprintf("%s/%s", x[POSwords][thisPOSindex],tags[thisPOSindex])
untokenizedAndTagged <- paste(tokenizedAndTagged, collapse = " ")
untokenizedAndTagged
```

}

```
Noun = lapply(txt, extractPOS, "NN")
```

I extract all noun words

```
[[1]]
[1] "tagging/NN example/NN John/NNP Doe/NNP"

[[2]]
[1] "OpenNLP/NNP texts/NNS"
```

How do I parse this output to get plain text without tags

```
tagging,exaple,John,Doe,OpenNLP,texts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(unlist(Noun), "\\w+(?=\\/)"))
#[1] "tagging" "example" "John"    "Doe"     "OpenNLP" "texts"
```

#### data

```
Noun <- list("tagging/NN example/NN John/NNP Doe/NNP", "OpenNLP/NNP texts/NNS")
```